# Using Event Listeners (Javascript, jQuery) to change BG color to a random color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, events, random

I am attempting a simple random background color generator. When a user clicks the button, the background color changes to a random RGB value. However, I also want the button itself to change to that random color when clicked.

I tried putting DOM manipulators in the event listener and in the random RGB function. However I keep getting this error message:

```
script.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined
    at randomBgColor (script.js:19)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:7)
randomBgColor @ script.js:19
(anonymous) @ script.js:7
```

The code is as follows:

```
<html>
<button id="press" class="button">Press me to change the background color!</button>
</html>
```

```
var changeColor = document.getElementById("press");
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("button");



changeColor.addEventListener("click", function(){
    randomBgColor();

})


function randomBgColor() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var bgColor = 'rgb(' + x + ',' + y + ',' + z + ')';
    console.log(bgColor);
   document.body.style.background = bgColor;
   button.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: In short, `getElementsByClassName` returns a list (note the plural "Elements"), not a single one. Note that you already have the button element as `changeColor`...

Comment: Was my answer satisfactory? If so, please mark one with an accepted checkmark and upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `changeColor` IS the button. Refactor this variable name to `button` like so:

```
var button = document.getElementById("press");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    randomBgColor();
})

function randomBgColor() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var bgColor = 'rgb(' + x + ',' + y + ',' + z + ')';
    console.log(bgColor);
    document.body.style.background = bgColor;
    button.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}
```

And as a bonus, here's a simplified version of your code that implements [randojs.com](https://randojs.com):

```js
var button = document.getElementById("press");
button.addEventListener("click", randomBgColor);

function randomBgColor() {
  var bgColor = 'rgb(' + rando(255) + ',' + rando(255) + ',' + rando(255) + ')';
  document.body.style.background = bgColor;
  button.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<button id="press">Change color!</button>
```